# How to show view controller when clicking on CollectionViewCell INSIDE a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has a CollectionView with many collectionViewCells.

Xcode crashes when I click on each CollectionViewCell.

Thid code is in the CustomTableViewCell.m file

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    JTSImageInfo *imageInfo = [[JTSImageInfo alloc] init];

    imageInfo.imageURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[self.fullSizeImagePath objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    imageInfo.referenceRect = self.superview.frame;
    imageInfo.referenceView = self.superview;

    // Setup view controller
    JTSImageViewController *imageViewer = [[JTSImageViewController alloc]
                                           initWithImageInfo:imageInfo
                                           mode:JTSImageViewControllerMode_Image
                                           backgroundStyle:JTSImageViewControllerBackgroundOption_Scaled];

    // Present the view controller.
    [imageViewer showFromViewController:self transition:JTSImageViewControllerTransition_FromOriginalPosition];
    imageViewer = nil;
}
```

The showFromViewController line crashes.

Advice?

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CustomTableViewCell view]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f85bb156600'

Comment: `self` is a cell, not a view controller.

Comment: i understand that rmaddy so how can I have it show in the viewcontroller where the cell is created?

Answer (score 0):

Your tableviewcell seems to be the collectionviews delegate/data source. This is generally not a good idea, so everytime you nest table/collectionviews inside cells the viewcontroller managing the outer collection should be the delegate/datasource for both. This way your viewcontroller implements the didSelectItemAtIndexPath and can present another VC

Answer (score 0):

You could add CollectionViewController instead of CollectionView in you tableViewCell so you can present a modal and the datasource/delegate will not be handled by your cell directly.